# Need help finding why there no equilibrium solutions to this function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why does the function $\Bbb dy/\Bbb dx=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)$ have no equilibrium solutions? I have already thought of the fact that for $\sin(x)$ to equal 0, $\cos(x)$ would equal 1 and that rules out that. So then I thought I could use some $x$-value such that $\cos(x)$ equals zero but $\sin(x)$ doesn’t equal zero but then you could find a $y$-value such that $\cos(y)$ equals zero, for example $\pi/2$, so I am stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by an equilibrium solution?  There are certainly no constant solutions:  $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are linearly independent functions, so there is no constant $y$ that makes the right side always $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Apologies if the question was phrased weirdly, the direct question I was asked was "Prove that there are no equilibrium solutions." Provided with the above-mentioned differential equation. To my understanding, I have to prove that there is no possibility that the above function can equal 0.

Comment: You can certainly have the right side of the equation be $0$ at some points $(x,y)$, in fact on a curve in the $xy$ plane.  However, this doesn't make an equilibrium solution. An equilibrium solution is a value of $y$ that would make $dy/dx = 0$ for **all** $x$.